# Change size of figure "removes" points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to adjust the size of my figure. However, the moment I do that, by adding `plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))` I don't see the dots anymore. The reason I want to change the size is mainly because of `ylabel` is not shown the way it is now.
[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

# Check out the Data
df = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/programs/data-science-path/linear_regression/honeyproduction.csv")
# print(df.head())
# print(df.columns)

prod_per_year = df.groupby(['year']).totalprod.mean().reset_index()
# print(prod_per_year)

X = prod_per_year['year']
X = X.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = prod_per_year['totalprod']

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Total production')
plt.show()

# Create and Fit a Linear Regression Model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)

# Print out the slope (regr.coef_) and the intercept (regr.intercept_)
print(regr.coef_)
print(regr.intercept_)

y_predict = regr.predict(X)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(X, y_predict)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the second answer in the duplicate target, as you are trying to change the size after the figure is already created.

Comment: `plt.figure` needs to come before `plt.scatter`, else you will have one figure with a scatter and one figure which is 10 by 5 inches.

Comment: That answered my question, thank you. I didn't realize the order was wrong. Now it makes sense.